# Google protocol buffer compiling error in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, protocol-buffers

I installed protobuf on cygwin and did a test (make check). All tests were successful. But when I try to compile the example file, I get an error.

```
/tmp/ccffZ4qk.o:add_person.cc:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN6google8protobuf8internal13empty_string_E[.refptr._ZN6google8protobuf8internal13empty_string_E]+0x0): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0xee3): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0xee3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0x1060): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::string const&, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0x1060): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::string const&, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0x22f7): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0x22f7): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0x2385): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0x2385): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0x253d): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::string const&, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0x253d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::string const&, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0x2739): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::string const&, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0x2739): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::string const&, unsigned char*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text$_ZN6google8protobuf8internal10WireFormat26VerifyUTF8StringNamedFieldEPKciNS2_9OperationES4_[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal10WireFormat26VerifyUTF8StringNamedFieldEPKciNS2_9OperationES4_]+0x2e): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::VerifyUTF8StringFallback(char const*, int, google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::Operation, char const*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text$_ZN6google8protobuf8internal10WireFormat26VerifyUTF8StringNamedFieldEPKciNS2_9OperationES4_[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal10WireFormat26VerifyUTF8StringNamedFieldEPKciNS2_9OperationES4_]+0x2e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::VerifyUTF8StringFallback(char const*, int, google::protobuf::internal::WireFormat::Operation, char const*)'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN6google8protobuf8internal23empty_string_once_init_E[.refptr._ZN6google8protobuf8internal23empty_string_once_init_E]+0x0): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_once_init_'
/tmp/ccJpLpoK.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN6google8protobuf8internal15InitEmptyStringEv[.refptr._ZN6google8protobuf8internal15InitEmptyStringEv]+0x0): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::InitEmptyString()'
```

Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

You probably aren't linking against the protobuf library. You need to pass `-lprotobuf` to the compiler. (You should probably `make install` first, if you haven't already.)